# How can Snoopy's Doghouse fit so many people?

Tags: peanuts

In this strip I count at least four people plus Snoopy himself going into the Doghouse. There is even room for one more, though the house *isn't so big*. How do they all fit?

[image]

Comment: Time And Relative Dimension In Space... It's bigger on the inside...

Comment: OMG SNOOPY IS A TIME LORD!

Comment: Also referenced [here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BiggerOnTheInside) (warning: TV Tropes).

Comment: For people voting to close this, if you can provide evidence that 5 people plus a dog can easily fit inside a small doghouse with multiple rooms I'll happily let this be closed. Until then I don't see how this is off topic.

Comment: Aren't "recreation rooms" usually in the basement?

Comment: @Pam I think it's personal choice really...

Comment: @MikeHarris The dog house is also referenced in episode *1x11 - New Dimensions* of *The Orville* alongside the TARDIS...

Comment: The same holds true for Oscar's trashcan and Pogo's treehouse.

Comment: VTO, it is established that some aspects of Snoopy are on topic, and how to fit so many people into a physical space that is too small sure feels like a Sci-Fi question to me.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Except I think it's an absurdist joke rather than a SFF event.

Comment: @MissMonicaE It is, however, a repeated "joke".

Comment: While it's silly to think of a dog house having a basement (and it would be difficult to see how there could be room, given what we can see inside the doghouse, and the positions of the kids going in), an underground expansion of the doghouse could explain this strip at least.

Comment: This is as simple as fitting lots of people in a clown car!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yeah, exactly, a running gag rather than anything with an "in-universe explanation"

Comment: @MissMonicaE so the answer is we don’t know how. That is still a valid answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't think there *is* a "how" to begin with. It's like asking "Why did the chicken want to get to the other side?"

Comment: @MissMonicaE I don’t understand your point and I see no need to keep this going now anyway. You invisibly disagree let’s just leave it at that.

Comment: I agree with the "most of Snoopy's house is underground" theory and think someone even mentions a basement in one of the strips.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure there's a physically correct answer. There are many aspects of "Peanuts" that don't make sense, but are there for the sake of comedy. If you are going to ask how so many people can fit into his doghouse, shouldn't you also ask how a dog can type (in English, I might add), or even how Snoopy is able to comfortably lay on top of his doghouse if the roof comes to a point? Half of the comics featuring Snoopy should have you asking "how is that possible?".

But that's what makes Peanuts so good. The strip is popular for its quaint humor and running gags, such as Lucy pulling away the football, or Charlie Brown always getting disrobed by line drives, not as much for its knee-slapping jokes. The size and quality of the inside of Snoopy's doghouse is no different than the latter two examples, except it isn't used quite as many times throughout the running of the strip. The idea that a tiny doghouse can have a recreation room, fit a pool table, and house many other items (including a Van Gogh painting) is ludicrous; that's what makes that particular strip funny. Below are a few other examples of strips that use the same gag of Snoopy's doghouse being bigger than it seems:
[image]
[image]

I suppose if one were to absolutely refuse to accept the humor of the situation, and demand a logical answer, it could be rationalized that the entire premise of Peanuts is similar to that of Calvin and Hobbes. That is, you never quite know what is reality and what is happening in the imagination of the children involved. This is often the case for Snoopy, as he is constantly fantasizing about fighting the Red Baron, or being in other action-packed situations, but we know that these are all in his head by the way the kids in the strip interact with him while he is wrapped up in one of these charades. It could be that his doghouse is normal sized, but the kids all want to make him feel better and so they participate in his illusions of owning a recreation room, pool table, etc, by squeezing into it and pretending to be impressed.

Overall, I think that the space inside of Snoopy's doghouse is supposed to remain a mystery, as it allowed Charles Schultz to give Snoopy whatever materials he needed for his next fantasy or adventure. Most comic strips take creative liberties, and I think that Snoopy's doghouse is just another silly gag that's funny purely because of the implausibility of it all. I mean, come on... how could a dog own a Van Gogh?

Comment: I don't see what relevance your first paragraph has at all, if you're going to say that you might as well add a similar paragraph to every post here. The second paragraph is kind of relevant but again more of an analysis of the joke rather than an actual answer. Then you're actual answer isn't really an answer. I appreciate the effort you put in here but it is essentially an extended comment rather than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: Or the main house is underground, and what we see is simply the entrance.

Comment: Bigger on the inside...

Comment: He must have had good insurance, too -- IIRC he got an Andrew Wyeth to replace the Van Gogh...

Answer (score 0):

Snoopy's house is bigger than it looks. Snoopy has a pool table, a Van Gogh, some record players, some books, and even a TV! One *Peanuts* comic showed Snoopy's house has a basement that gets flooded by the rain. I believe Snoopy's basement is underground along with Snoopy's belongings (for the pictures click here [1](https://storquest.com/blog/what-s-in-snoopy-s-dog-house))

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Do you have any images of the inside of Snoopy's doghouse? That would make your answer easier to verify.

Answer (score -1):

Peanuts comics however don't have much evidence about Snoopy's house size but    a website said to fits up 7 kids plus woodstock the bird.

Comment: Please note that this question already has an answer that includes a comic that describes the space inside the doghouse.  Your answer doesn't even link to the website, much less cite any primary sources; you should make sure when posting a new answer that you have something new to contribute that isn't already covered.